# SendEmail failed.[...] first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY when Messaging.sendEmail via guest user on a site

Tags: email-template, singleemailmessage, send-email, guest-user, org-wide-email

We have a public site which uses a guest user to execute the logic of all its aura components/classes...
We are facing an issue when this guest user tries to send an email through Messaging.sendEmail(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage). The error message is the next one:

`14:01:16:284 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [112]|e|"common.apex.methods.MessagingStaticMethods$EmailExecutionException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 003XXXXX: [targetObjectId, 003XXXXX]"|0x6a5c339c`

We have the problem with the contact object, and the guest profile have all permissions on this object. We have permissions too in 'Send email', 'Mass email' System permissions.

The template we are using is a classic template, and when we are sending the email via apex, we are using OrgWideEmailAddress (email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId) method.

Code we are using:

```
public static EmailTemplate emailTemplateToSend;
public static OrgWideEmailAddress orgWideEmailAddressFrom;
[...] The previous variables are initialized and informed by some queries

private static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage sendEmailMessageToContacts(Contact cont){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplateToSend.Id);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(cont.Id);// Any contact or User id of your record
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailAddressFrom.Id);
        mail.setToAddresses(new list<string>{cont.email});
        if(listEmailsToSendCCO != null) mail.setBccAddresses(listEmailsToSendCCO);
        //mail.setWhatId(YourCustomObjectRecord.id); // Enter your record Id whose merge field you want to add in template
        return mail;
    }
```

And we are calling this method:

```
[...]
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] lSingleEmailMess = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        
for(Contact cont: lContactsToSend){
   lSingleEmailMess.add(sendEmailMessageToContacts(cont));
}
            
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(lSingleEmailMess); <--- ERROR THERE
[...]
```

The problem may be that we cannot add the guest profile on the "Setup->Organization-Wide Addresses", because it doesnt show in the specified email profiles list.

Some other ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: This is likely about sharing not object permissions. Have you verified if guests can see the records of contacts?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment @manjit5190. I verified it. I am checking too in apex code with isAccessible() fields. For example full object: Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isAccessible() or all the fields template is using, for example email : Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Email.isAccessible(). And it returns me true in all cases.

Comment: As I mentioned it is not about object permissions. What you are checking is object permissions. I am asking if the user has access to contact record? A simple check is to share the contact manually with the community user and try the test again, if it works then you need to review your sharing model.

Comment: Firstly, sorry for the first misunderstanding. You were right, and it is all about the sharing model. When we have shared the account (because we cannot share the contact directly) we have solved it. Thank you very much!